# Aggregate pipeline throws the error "A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field."

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, database

```
db.audiofiles.aggregate({
    $match: {
        privacy: { $ne: "same" },
        date: { "$eq": "2017/04/25" },
        deleted: 0
    },
    $group: { "_id": "$to_email" }
});
```

I have used `$match` but still it is showing pipeline error as below.

```
assert: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.",
    "code" : 16435
} : aggregate failed
```

Comment: Pipeline is an array. Add square brackets between parentheses.

Comment: db.audiofiles.aggregate({[$match:{privacy:{$ne:"same"},date:{"$eq": "2017/04/25" },deleted:0]},$group:{"_id":"$to_email"}});
getting error like ->
2017-04-24T14:46:37.021+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ] in computed property name @(shell):1:32

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to place your pipeline stages in an [array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#stage-operators), i.e. documents pass through the stages in sequence.

> ```
> db.collection.aggregate( [ { <stage> }, ... ] )
> ```

The **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline step operators should be in their own object/document, not as part of the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline step. You aggregate pipeline should be

```
db.audiofiles.aggregate([
    /* match pipeline */
    {
        "$match": {
            "privacy": { "$ne": "same" },
            "date": { "$eq": "2017/04/25" },
            "deleted": 0
        }
    },
    /* group pipeline */
    {
        "$group": { 
            "_id": "$to_email", 
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
]);
```

Or create the pipeline steps as object variables that you can push to an array and that array becomes the pipeline to use as the **[`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate)** method argument:

```
/* match pipeline */
var match = {
    $match: {
        privacy: { $ne: "same" },
        date: { "$eq": "2017/04/25" },
        deleted: 0
    }
},
/* group pipeline */
group = {
    $group: { 
        "_id": "$to_email", 
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
};

db.audiofiles.aggregate([match, group]);
```

---

If you don't get any response from the above then try to run the aggregate pipeline with just one step:

```
db.audiofiles.aggregate([match]);
```

The results from the match step will be piped to the next stage so if you aren't getting any results that means the **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline step hasn't found any matching documents. Change some of the parameters to see if there are any results.

Comment: I didnt get any reponse on entering the above query in my mongo terminal?

Comment: Then it either means your `$match` pipeline is not returning any matches or that your are running the aggregate operation on the wrong collection. Try different parameters with the `$match` pipeline for debugging or run the pipeline with just the `$group` step and see if it returns any documents.

Comment: audiofiles.aggregate({$group:{"_id":"$to_email"} });
if i type the above query i am getting the records from my collection..
audiofiles.find({privacy:{$ne:"same"},date:{"$eq":"24/04/2017" },deleted:0}}).
if i type the above query i am getting a set of response..

Comment: Then `db.audiofiles.aggregate([match]);` should return the same set of response you would get with `db.audiofiles.find({privacy:{$ne:"same"},date:{"$eq":"24/04/201‌​7" },deleted:0}})` as `$match` uses standard MongoDB queries. If that works, then you should be ok to add the next `$group` step to the pipeline `db.audiofiles.aggregate([match, group]);`

Comment: This is what i get when i type db.audiofiles.aggregate([match]);


error ===> 2017-04-24T15:11:22.297+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] ReferenceError: match is not defined :
@(shell):1:26

Comment: You either need to create the variables that hold the pipeline stages to put in the array as in the above answer OR just run the aggregate operation with the operators as `db.audiofiles.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "privacy": { "$ne": "same" },
            "date": { "$eq": "2017/04/25" },
            "deleted": 0
        } } ])`

Comment: Working perfectly :) Thank You

Answer (score 7):

**I was also facing same error.** 
My code was :

```
 db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
      {
          "$lookup":
          {     
              from: 'songs',
              localField: '_id',
              foreignField: 'artistId',              
              as: 'abc'              
          },
          "$project":
          {
              "name":1,
              "status":1,
              "abc":{"artistId":1, "name":1}
          }
      }
])
```

**I resolved by adding { }.**

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
      {
          "$lookup":
          {     
              from: 'songs',
              localField: '_id',
              foreignField: 'artistId',              
              as: 'abc'              
          }
      }, // added braces
      { 
          "$project":
          {
              "name":1,
              "status":1,
              "abc":{"artistId":1, "name":1}
          }
      } // added braces
])
```

> NOTE:: Make sure $lookup and $project should be in different {} braces like :

```
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([ { $lookup:{} }, { $project: {} } ])
```

> My code was :

```
 db.getCollection('users').aggregate([ { $lookup:{},  $project: {} } ])
```